# Can ZFC prove reflection on stages of the cumulative hierarchy whose size is equal to their height?

Tags: set-theory, reflection

Working in first order logic with equality and membership, add the following axiom schemata:

1. **Specification:**$(\exists! i:i=\{x \in A \mid \phi\})$; if   $``i"$ not used by $\phi$.
2. **Reflection:**$(\phi \to \exists \alpha: \phi^{V_\alpha} \land |V_\alpha|=\alpha)$; if $``\alpha"$ not used by $\phi$.

Where: $V_\alpha$ and $||$ are defined in the customary manner; and $\phi^{V_\alpha}$ is the bounded by $V_\alpha$ form of formula $\phi$.

This system proves all axioms of ZFC.

I know that ZFC proves $(\phi \to \exists \alpha: \phi^{V_\alpha})$, also it proves that every set belongs to some stage $V_\alpha$ where $|V_\alpha|=\alpha$. But, does it prove the Reflection axiom stated above? Or can this axiom be actually inconsistent with ZFC?

Comment: Every sentence reflects on a club. The $\beth$ fixed points form a club. The intersection of two clubs is a club. Finally, clubs are nonempty.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, let me know if I got what you said correctly. By reflects on a club you mean that the sentence [either all variables bound, or one with substituted parameters] is true in a club of stages, i.e. the class of all $V_\alpha$s in which that sentence is true forms a club, and that some of those $V_\alpha$s must be indexed by $\beth$ fixed points, otherwise there is an intersection of two clubs that is empty (i.e. not a club), which cannot be, so ZFC  proves this form of reflection schema.